# Change AutoScaleMode, or from a FlowLayoutPanel to a TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, winforms, scale, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

The controls on my FlowLayoutPanel look perfect on my machine, but are all goofed up (that's a technical phrase for "misaligned") on another's machine. Mine is XP, his is Windows 7, but I don't know if that's the reason for the mismatch or whether its screen resolution or something else.

I did notice that the FlowLayoutPanel is extremely touchy/finnicky - even changing the BorderStyle at design time can cause the controls to rearrange so that they no longer align with each other.

I saw on a StackOverflow article a suggestion to change the (form's) AutoScaleMode property, but the poster didn't specify to what (or from what; I guess the default property value is "Font").

Would switching from FlowLayoutPanel to TableLayoutPanel provide a more consistent visual experience between DPI settings or whatever the issue is?

BTW: WPF is not an option for us at this time.